# Magento 2 Cannot create cache directory

Tags: magento-2.1, composer

I'm running `composer update` command, but it's showing error, that says :

> Cannot create cache directory
>   /home/111111.cloudwaysapps.com/esdasrdss/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.magento.com/,
>   or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache Cannot create
>   cache directory
>   /home/111111.cloudwaysapps.com/esdasrdss/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.magento.com/,
>   or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache Cannot create
>   cache directory
>   /home/111111.cloudwaysapps.com/esdasrdss/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/,
>   or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache Cannot create
>   cache directory
>   /home/111111.cloudwaysapps.com/esdasrdss/.composer/cache/files/, or
>   directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache

I noticed here, the path should be `/home/111111.cloudwaysapps.com/esdasrdss/public_html/` instead `/home/111111.cloudwaysapps.com/esdasrdss/`. Missing `/public_html`. Magento2 is installed at `/public_html` directory.

How to Change Composer Cache directory ?

Anyone can help to change this path accordingly ? As it doesn't have write permission at `/home/111111.cloudwaysapps.com/esdasrdss/` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I fixed it by just adding `cache-dir` config at `composer.json` file :

```
...

"config": {
    ...

    "cache-dir":"/home/111111.cloudwaysapps.com/esdasrdss/public_html/",

    ...
},

...
```

Hope this help others