# Magento2 can not update to Version 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade magento **2.2.2** to **2.3.0**.

Php version 7.1.19(>7.1.3+)
i have run command :

```
...
composer update
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

======O/p=====

```
Module 'Magento_Variable':
Module 'Apptrian_ImageOptimizer':
Module 'Magento_Backend':
Module 'Magento_Config':
Module 'Customweb_Base':
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Emipro_Custompayment':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Module 'Magento_Cms':
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_Quote':
Module 'Magento_Email':
Module 'Magento_Rule':
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Running schema recurring...Unique constraint violation found
```

Comment: Are you check this variant? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194126/magento-2-cannot-create-cache-directory

Answer (score 2):

It seems this can help you to resolve your issue: [Magento 2 Cannot create cache directory](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194126/magento-2-cannot-create-cache-directory)

Also, you can double check permissions for your project. It can be an issue with owner for `~/.composer` or something like this.

Comment: that is a not problem,may be it conflicts with somr extension